# Detect bounding box of tables in PDF page

Tags: machine-learning, density-function, image-processing

I am new to Machine Learning, doing courses and reading papers, and would like to solve the following problem as my learning journey:

Given a PDF page I would like to detect the bounding boxes of all tables on the given page.

Converting to an image or other semi-structured format is fine during processing.

What model and approach would be suitable for this task?
What would be the features and output of the algorithm ([(x1,y1;x2,y2),...] coordinates)?

What would be good papers, books, videos, articles to start with related to this specific problem?

Comment: Consider PDFplumber python package for Bounding Box of each table present in PDF file.